# python equivalent for java byte negation

Tags: java, python

What is python equivalent for this java code please?

code in java:

```
bytes[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];
```

I thought it is `bytes[i] = ~bytes[i]` but I am getting error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'

Comment: Please show what is `bytes` in your python code.

Comment: probably a string. As it works with `bytes` or `bytearray` objects.

Comment: You'll need to mask to get the same value as java though. `(~bytes[i] & 0xFF)`

Comment: it is simplier with `bytes[i] ^ 0xFF`

Comment: all covered in the duplicate :)